# Apache camel route send data to wss websocket on stomp

Tags: java, websocket, apache-camel, spring-websocket, spring-camel

I have create wss socket using springboot and it works fine I have tested using online tool as well as springboot client.
the socket is open at endpoint `wss://spring-ou5b.onrender.com/web-socket-endpoint and received message on /app/message`
Now I am trying to send data to this socket using apache camel repo at
https://github.com/rksharma1401/apache-camel-microservice

Below is the route

```
  package learn.camelmicorservices.routes;

import org.apache.camel.InOut;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ActiveMqSenderRouter extends RouteBuilder {
 
    @Override
    @InOut
    @Produce(value ="app/message" )
    public void configure() throws Exception {
int i=0;
        from("timer:wss-timer?period=5000").transform().constant("{\"name\":\"new"+(++i)+"\"}" )
            .log("Created"+"${body}")
            .to("wss://spring-ou5b.onrender.com/web-socket-endpoint?sendToAll=true")
            .log("After End"+"${body}");

    }
}
```

but I get error as

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could
> be found for: wss://.....

which camel componet jar is needed for wss

I have tried websocket,vertx,ahc but they don't send data or gives other errors

Comment: I can see that you keep trying on your project, could you make finally work? or this question is still actual?

Comment: No i can't , tried  alot but nothing works

Comment: Any idea on accessing wss:// using camel ?